# Motorola 68k array with stacks

Tags: arrays, assembly, stack, motorola, easy68k

im currently trying to load values of an array, push them onto the stack but im having some issues.

I have the following code (Using EASY68K:

```
    ORG $8000
START:
    LEA $9100,sp
    MOVE #array,-(sp)

    ORG $9000
array DC.B '1,2,3,4,5,6',0
sum DS.L 1
```

When I try to move the the top of my stack, with

```
MOVE.B (sp),D1
```

I get 60, but shouldnt it be 06? Another issue is when I do

```
MOVE.B 2(sp),D1
```

I get FF, instead of the next number, which I expect to be 05.

Comment: `MOVE #array,-(sp)` You realize that what you're doing here is store the value $9000 _in memory_ at address $90FE, right?

Comment: Also, having quotes around the array looks like a mistake. '6' != 6.

Comment: Your definition of `array` looks like the string `"1,2,3,4,5,6"`, null terminated. Is that what you intended? When you say, *I get 60* how are you observing 60? Are you using a debugger?